# W3 total cache - cache refresh programmatically

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I am building a Digg like website in WordPress.

After installing W3 Total Cache, I noticed certain elements such as number of votes (and voters ids) per post are cached even though they shouldn't be (at least not after a user votes for an article).
I assume it is not possible to prevent specific elements in a page from being cached (or is it?), so I thought of triggering page cache refresh programmatically.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21):

if you want to flush the cache you can do that:
the plugin has functions for that

```
<?php 

flush_pgcache()  //page cache
flush_dbcache()  // database cache
flush_minify()  // minify cache
flush_all() //all caches

?>
```

and you just need to call  it like this:

```
<?php 
 $w3_plugin_totalcache->flush_all();
?>
```

and that is basically the answer to the question in the title 
"cache refresh programmatically"

Comment: Can you please explicitly define how you instantiated the $w3_plugin_totalcache object?

Comment: Partially helpful, how did you instantiate that variable?

Comment: declare a new instance of the class, and then reference that method. https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/w3-total-cache/trunk/CacheFlush.php. 
if(class_exists('CacheFlush') ){
    $CacheFlush = new CacheFlush;
    $CacheFlush::flush_post(get_option('page_on_front'));
  }

Answer (score 12):

To flush a single page by post id in w3tc v0.9.3 I found this worked:

```
if (function_exists('w3tc_pgcache_flush_post')){
 w3tc_pgcache_flush_post($post_id);
}
```

Comment: Where would you place this code? This looks like it runs on every page load (for that ID). Is there no way to prevent to caching completely?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Could you find out with which hook we can use this code ?

Comment: Extra hooks are not needed if the event your custom code/plugin attaches to executes after plugins have loaded, which is typically the case. All available functions are in `w3-total-cache-api.php` in the W3TC's plugin dir.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful for me now in Dec 2018. I needed a way to flush the cache of the home page once the client visited a certain page (a settings page to display when an agent is available). This is very useful for specific pages, but it would be nice if there was a function that flushed ALL caches like the Purge All Caches does!

Answer (score 11):

Bainternet's solution didn't seem to work for me.

I'm successfully using this alternative snippet within a plugin, loaded at the **admin_init** action:

```
// Clear all W3 Total Cache
if( class_exists('W3_Plugin_TotalCacheAdmin') )
{
    $plugin_totalcacheadmin = & w3_instance('W3_Plugin_TotalCacheAdmin');

    $plugin_totalcacheadmin->flush_all();

    echo __('<div class="updated"><p>All <strong>W3 Total Cache</strong> caches successfully emptied.</p></div>');
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone out there.

Comment: I can confirm that kevinlearynet's solution works with W3 Total Cache version 0.9.2.4. It broke for [my plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/) after that upgrade, and this works a treat. Thank you!
Paul.

Comment: I'm trying to run this from the command line. Can I ask how you loaded the W3_Plugin_TotalCacheAdmin class? I tried requiring wp-load.php to no avail.

Answer (score 10):

W3 Total Cache supports fragment caching. From FAQ:

```
How do I implement fragment caching? 

Edit your templates to with the following syntax to ensure that dynamic features remain so:

Example 1:
<!-- mfunc any PHP code --><!-- /mfunc -->

Example 2:
<!-- mfunc -->any PHP code<!-- /mfunc -->

Example 3:
<!--MFUNC           -->
                                      echo rand();
<!--/mfunc -->

Example 4:
<!-- mclude path/to/file.php --><!-- /mclude -->

Example 5:
<!-- mclude -->path/to/file.php<!-- /mclude -->
```

Comment: Thanks Rast. But when I use any of the above examples, I get an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: @user1567 you probably have mismatch with opening/closing `<?php ?>` tags. I hadn't used these yet so don't have practical snippet to show.

Comment: For one thing, I would like to load functions.php without caching it.
The following code in functions.php triggered the error above:
<?php 
<!-- mclude -->require_once(functions2.php)<!-- /mclude -->
?>
What is wrong with the code?

Comment: @user1567 according to examples it should be something like `?><!-- mclude -->functions2.php<!-- /mclude --><?php` (I think :)

Comment: Not able to get to work fragment caching. My issue described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125413/w3-total-cache-and-fragment-cache-not-able-get-it-to-work

Answer (score 6):

None of the above worked for me in my plugin. However this worked! Confirmed working for version 0.9.2.4 of w3tc.

```
if (function_exists('w3tc_dbcache_flush')) { w3tc_dbcache_flush(); }
```

I did a 
"
$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `sb_settings`.`f_fb_app_id`,`sb_settings`.`f_fb_secret` FROM `sb_settings`" );
"
and was surprised the values f_fb_secret and f_fb_app_id was the same every time. It was obviously the w3tc cacheing the result of the query. So I added a dbcache flush in my modify page for the sb_settings table.

Should you want to clear page cache, then just use w3tc_pgcache_flush instead.

Comment: I'd like the downvoter to say why he downvoted. Is there anything wrong in my answer?

Comment: This worked for me: if (function_exists('w3tc_flush_all')) { w3tc_flush_all(); }

You can find other functions in w3-total-cache-api.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet to make sure your PHP runs regardless of whether caching is on or off. Yes, you have to write/call your function twice.

`<!-- mfunc echo 'caching ON'; --><?php echo 'caching OFF'; ?><!-- /mfunc -->`

---

(I think) this is how it works:

- The mfunc conditionals *replace* php tags.
- If caching is **OFF**, php inside mfunc comments appear in your markup as a HTML comments. `<!-- mfunc echo "hello?"; -->` Keep this in mind depending on how happy you are for people to see your PHP (only happens when caching is off).