# How to force content refresh of a page that has been loaded previously by the user?

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache, theme-twenty-eleven

How can any page on the site be forced to refresh or load content by ignoring anything in cache, everytime a visitor visits the page for the second time? The website uses twentyeleven & w3tc (browser caching disabled at the moment).

Comment: Ultimately, you probably can't but why would you want to try in the first place?

Comment: I want the members of the website to be able to see any changes that have been made to their 'profile' instantly. So for example, new member was added under category - somecategory after a payment on the phone, since the member has already visited the page, he can not see himself added on this page. So everytime he has to be told to hit F5. This is a stupid (and perhaps not ideal) situation but I have been trying to find a workaround for the past 2 days. I would like to emphasize that it is not a case of ideal implementation of theme but a case where the only question is - Can it be achieved?

Comment: Does this help? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/7112/21376

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since, your site already uses W3 Total Cache plugin, let me provide a solution based on it.

Please visit yoursite's wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_browsercache and look for the text "Set cache control header". Check this option, if it is unchecked, and then choose "no-cache" for the "Cache control policy". This needs to be done in three places...

1. CSS & JS
2. HTML & XML
3. Media & Other files

[image]

If you do not wish to use W3 Total Cache plugin for some reason, you may set the following in 'htaccess' file or in Apache configuration, assuming your server has [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) module...

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
```